# Pseudo determinant of product of two square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be square symmetric matrices. $A$ is singular and $B$ is non-singular. Is there a way to decompose:

> $Det(AB)$ in terms of $Det(A)$ and $det(B)$.

$Det(.)$ refers to the pseudo determinant and $det(.)$ refers to the usual determinant of a square non-singular matrix.

Comment: [Definition of the pseudo-determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant)

Answer (score 3):

We can decompose it, but not in terms of $\operatorname{Det}(A)$ and $\det(B)$.

Suppose that $A,B$ are $n \times n$ and let $k = \dim \ker A$ We note that $\operatorname{Det}(A) = \operatorname{Tr}(\wedge^k(A))$, where $\wedge$ denotes the [exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Linear_algebra). It follows that
$$
\operatorname{Det}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(\wedge^k(AB)) = 
\operatorname{Tr}(\wedge^k(A)\wedge^k(B))
$$
This can be expressed as the following sum.  Let $S_k$ denote the subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with size $k$.  For any $R,C \in S_k$, let $A[R,C]$ denote the submatrix of $A$ consisting of the rows from $R$ and columns from $C$.  With that, we have
$$
\operatorname{Det}(AB) = \sum_{R \in S_k} \det((AB)[R,R]) = \sum_{R,C \in S_k} \det(A[R,C])\det(B[C,R]).
$$
This is an inconvenient sum in general, but it is reasonable if $k$ is either small or close to $n$. For small $k$, however, there are more efficient methods.

---

Where $A$ has rank $n-1$, we can sometimes write this nicely in terms of the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) matrix. In particular, we have
$$
\operatorname{Det}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(AB)) = 
\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(B)\operatorname{adj}(A)) = 
\det(B)\cdot \operatorname{tr} (B^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(A)).
$$
Moreover, in the case that $A$ has eigenvalue $0$ with algebraic multiplicity $1$, if we have a unit vector $x$ that spans the kernel of $A$ and a unit vector $y$ that spans the kernel of $A^T$ and if $x^Ty \neq 0$ (which is guaranteed if $\operatorname{Det}(A) \neq 0$), then we can write $\operatorname{adj}(A) = \frac{\operatorname{Det}(A)}{x^Ty}\cdot xy^T$ so that
$$
\operatorname{Det}(AB) = \frac{1}{x^Ty}\det(B)\cdot \operatorname{tr} (B^{-1}\operatorname{Det}(A)\cdot xy^T ) = \frac 1{x^Ty}\det(B) \operatorname{Det}(A) \cdot y^TB^{-1}x
\\ = \det(B) \operatorname{Det}(A) \cdot \frac{y^TB^{-1}x}{y^Tx}.
$$

Comment: I think in the summation we should have $C$ instead of $S$.

Comment: Can you also help me to understand how we can write $Det(AB) = tr(adj(AB))$?

Comment: @shani That's right. Regarding your second comment: if $A$ has rank $n-1$, then the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $\operatorname{Det}(A)$ with multiplicity $1$. The trace is the sum of all eigenvalues, so the Det of $A$ is also the trace of the adjugate of $A$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm commenting that this has applications for statisticians dealing with Intrinsic Conditionally AutoRegressive spatiotemporal models so as to help Google direct people here.

Comment: @JohnMadden I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: @BenGrossmann I had a slightly different problem (posdef B is pre and post mult by A, which is an orthogonal projector), but just plugging in your formula and ignoring the postmultiplication seemed to work, (luckily, as the exterior algebra of multicovectors is mysterious to me :)).

Comment: @JohnMadden Interesting. I don't know if you've posted about it, but I'm very much inclined to think that there is an easier/more elegant approach taking advantage of the "niceness" of $A$ and $B$, assuming that "posdef" here implies that $B$ is symmetric. But hey, if it works, it works.

Comment: @JohnMadden Also, when you say "ignoring the postmultiplication", do you mean that you're ignoring the $\frac{y^TB^{-1}x}{y^Tx}$ factor?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Maybe I should post it as a separate problem after work. No, I mean that it seems like $|\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{P}|_+=|\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}|_+$, at least for the cases I've examined (and hence I can use your formula).

Comment: @JohnMadden Okay, that makes sense. In general, $(PB)P$ and $P(PB) = PB$ will have the same non-zero eigenvalues, so as long as $PBP$ has the same rank as $PB$ (which it will if $B$ is *symmetric* and positive definite), $PB$ and $PBP$ will have the same eigenvalues so that $|PBP|_+ = |PB|_+$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, consider
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
A_2 &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
B &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then, $\operatorname{Det} A_1 = \operatorname{Det} A_2 = 1$, but $\operatorname{Det}(A_1 B) = 1$ and $\operatorname{Det} (A_2 B) = 2$. That is, $\operatorname{Det}(AB)$ is not purely a function of $\operatorname{Det} A$ and $\det B$.