# What is the adjoint for a non-invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that we can find matrix's inverse using the relation $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{Det(A)} \cdot Adj(A)$. But what about the adjoint when the matrix is non-invertible? Is it still defined?

And if the answer is yes, what would be its use for a non-invertible square matrix?

Still some properties like $\text{Adj}(AB)=\text{Adj}(B)\text{Adj}(A)$ valid?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix .

Comment: Yes, the property you mention still holds, as do most of the properties on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties).

Comment: You might also be interested in the relationship between the adjugate and the [pseudo-determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3732640/81360)